# Creating an mySQL UPDATE statement from values in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

Due to some unforeseen circumstances, an Open Cart table of customers that I have has had their `address_id` reset to 0 for all records, which now causes problems.

I do have a backup of the sql, however I only have it in INSERT form but since a few things have changed since that last backup, I'd prefer it to be an UPDATE statement.

So, rather than:

```
INSERT INTO oc49_customer (customer_id,firstname,surname,address_id etc.) VALUES ('1','Joe','Bloggs','1' ...), ('2','Jane','Doe','2'...)
```

I would prefer:

```
UPDATE oc49_customer SET address_id = 1 WHERE customer_id = 1
```

Is there a way to easily do this, since now I have two tables - the existing customer table and also a customer_temp table which is the backup with the correct address ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, use a subquery

```
Update oc49_customer
  set address_id =
      (Select address_id from oc49_customer_old
       where customer_id = oc49_customer.customer_id)
From oc49_customer
```

Also try it without the From clause at all:

```
Update oc49_customer
  set address_id =
      (Select address_id from oc49_customer_old
       where customer_id = oc49_customer.customer_id)
```

Comment: thanks - I don't understand the last From line though? based on the fact that my backup is called `oc49_customer_old` and my live is `oc49_customer` can you rewrite using these names to help me understand?

Comment: When I run the query, it tells me there is a syntax error near `FROM oc49_customer c` (I used c because new seems to be a reserved keyword)

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `WHERE` clause, not a `FROM` clause?

Comment: As I am not familiar with MySQL syntax, I have modified the SQL to make is more vanilla, without aliases.

Comment: And no, it should not be a Where clause at the end, you want to update ALL the rows, right. The subquery is a "correlated" subquery, which means that the value of the subquery, (being set into `Address_id` for every row, is the value of `address_id` in the matching row in the old table.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE oc49_customer
SET address_id = (SELECT address_id
  FROM oc49_customer_old
  WHERE (oc49_customer_id = oc49_customer_old_id)
WHERE EXISTS ( oc49_customer_id = oc49_customer_old_id )
```